# Running oracle queries through azure databricks

Tags: oracle, azure-databricks

Hi I created a notebook in azure databricks to extract a table from an oracle database. I get the error DPI-1047 cannot locate a 64 bit oracle client library. I guess I have to have an oracle client library running on my cluster. I tried to research the issue and found many posts where people said I needed an init script for the oracle client. I couldnt find how to make that init script however. I also found on this website

https://medium.com/@srijansahay/connecting-sql-server-oracle-mysql-and-postgresql-from-azure-services-using-python-789e93d879b4

the following code:

```
%sh
mkdir -p /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/193000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64–19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip
sudo sh -c “echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf”
sudo ldconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_3:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This code is however for Linux. How do I modify it for windows? Here is what I have so far:

```
%sh
mkdir -p /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/nt/instantclient/19800/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.zip
sudo sh -c “echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_8 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf”
sudo ldconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_8:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I think everything past the unzip is incorrect. Thanks for the help in advance I'm very new to databricks.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no library path and path Separation in Windows we need to use PATH for both instead. At the end of the script you place the python stuff.

```
Rem ic.cmd
C:
Set ORABAS = "\opt\oracle"
cd %ORABAS%
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/nt/instantclient/19600/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip
set ORACLE_HOME=%ORABAS%\instantclient_19_3
set TNS_ADMIN=%ORACLE_HOME%
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%;%PATH%
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got a syntax error on the first line and I'm not sure exactly how to fix it though.

Comment: So I'm using databricks and I put your code in a cell before my python code in a notebook. Do I need to have a line to indicate what this non python code is? In my example they use %sh to denote that the cell is for shell commands. Is Rem a comment? Can this be run in the azure bricks notebook? Is this what I need for the init file? I'm very sorry I just started azure bricks today.